# Scala Match Case structure and traversing a List with odd terms cs and m?

Tags: scala, list, case, matching, pruning

I am trying to understand this piece of code [here](https://github.com/tonyskn/coursera-scala/blob/master/w1-recfun/src/main/scala/recfun/Main.scala)

```
  def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = (money, coins) match {
     case (0, _) => 1
     case (m, _) if m < 0 => 0
     case (_, cs)  if cs.isEmpty => 0
     case (m, cs) => countChange(m - cs.head, cs) + countChange(m, cs.tail) 
  }
}
```

where I cannot understand the pairs `(0,_)`, `(m,_)`, `(_,cs)` and `(m,cs)` because the terms `m` and `cs` are undefined in the body of the code.

**What is this construction in traversing the List called? A pair of some matching patterns?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list is being traversed recursively. This construct is called [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html)

You can read it like:

> If the tuple `(money, coins)` is a tuple whose first value is `0` then return `1` ignore the second value of the tuple
>
> If the tuple `(money, coins)` is a tuple has a first value below `0` then return 0 ignore the second value of the tuple.

And so on...

The `_` is used in pattern matching to simbolize that we don't care what that parameter is, it can be anything

Pattern matching in Scala is backed by the `unapply` method of Objects, read more [about extractors](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html). Meaning that for each `case` the method `unapply` will be called with the tuple `(money, coins)` as argument and if determines that it is a match it will pass the respective first value and second value to the `case` clauses.

Example:

The statement `case (m, _) => ...` will lead to the call `Tuple2.unapply((money, coins))`

### Note

Case classes already define `unapply` methods for us. That's why you can use them in pattern matching 'out of the box'. `Tuple2` is a case class.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of pattern matching, which is being used to recursively traverse your list of coins.  Here is the same code re-written with comments, the important thing to know is that each `case` statement is matching a possible pattern of the tuple, and the `_` are used for ignoring pieces of the tuple.

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {

  // Construct a tuple for pattern matching on
  val tuple: (Int, List[Int])  = (money, coins)

  tuple match {

    // Check to see if money == 0
    case (0, _) => 1

    // m represents money, use a guard to check if m is negative 
    case (m, _) if m < 0 => 0

    // cs represents coins, use a guard statement check for empty list
    case (_, cs) if cs.isEmpty => 0

    // Recursive step.  Since the patterns are tried in order, we 
    // now know that if we make it to here m (money) is non-zero 
    // and non-negative, and we know that cs (coins) is a non-empty 
    // list.  Now we can  call the recursive function safely on 
    // the head of the list
    case (m, cs) => countChange(m - cs.head, cs) + countChange(m, cs.tail)
  }

}
```

Comment: I think the last recursive call is brilliant, any idea whether it has some specific name? Tail recursion?

Comment: This is not tail recursion (although it looks like it) because the last operation would actually be the addition `+` and not the recursive call

Answer (score 1):

This construct is often used to match on more than one variable at the same time. At the top of the `match`, you see `(money, coins)`. This means that it's matching on the *pair* of both `money` and `coins`. It doesn't have a name, because it's perfectly ordinary matching on two values simultaneously.

> I cannot understand the pairs `(0,_)`, `(m,_)`, `(_,cs)` and `(m,cs)` because the terms `m` and `cs` are undefined in the body of the code.

These terms *are* defined in the code. The `case`s define them. That's what matching and destructuring is all about.

```
(money, coins) match {
   case (0, _) => 1 // If money == 0, then coins is ignored and we return 1
   case (m, _) if m < 0 => 0 // m = money, coins is ignored. If m < 0, return 0
   case (_, cs)  if cs.isEmpty => 0 // money is ignored, cs = coins.
                                    // If we have no coins, return 0.
   case (m, cs) => countChange(m - cs.head, cs) + countChange(m, cs.tail)
   // Otherwise, m = money, cs = coins. Recurse down the list with
   // countChange(money - coins.head, coins) + countChange(money, coins.tail)
}
```

The reason for the tupling `(money, coins)` is because these patterns depend on *both* `money` and `coins`. You'd either need to nest `match`s (ugly) or do even more ugly boolean logic in order to replicate these semantics.